# Clustering using MLP on non-labeled dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, mlp

How to use Multilayered Perceptron for clustering like K-Means on non-labeled dataset.
I've MNIST dataset with labels but i was wanted to perform clustering algorithm with MLP.
Any idea?

Comment: Clustering is usually unsupervised, MLPs are usually supervised. What is your exact problem? Can you define a distance metric? Would you expect the MLP to define such?

Comment: @PeterLang I want to cluster non-labeled dataset (unsupervised) with MLP like K-Means.

Comment: By MLP do you mean just stacked linear layers or any neural network? it feels like what's important here is the objective (kmeans' is not differentiable), instead of the architecture.

Comment: I think it's simply impossible to apply the multilayer perceptron ("vanilla" neural network) to unlabelled data, because neural networks normally work with _labeled_ data only. It doesn't seem to make sense to train a neural network on unlabelled data. (What would training even look like then?) Neural networks are _supervised_ models (require _examples_ of correct solutions and thus need labels), but clustering is normally _unsupervised_ (doesn't need labels).

Comment: that's not necessarily true, transformers networks pretraining work without labels. Is all about how you define the objective task and loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: if the problem is restricted to use an MLP exclusively, I think you're looking for differentiable objectives for clustering. (K-Means objective is not differentiable because of the finding the centroids part). I think this is not a 'mainstream' approach to clustering, but certainly there seems to be some work to use deep networks to optimize clustering (differentiable) objectives:

1. [Differentiable Deep Clustering with Cluster Size Constraints](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.09036.pdf)
   : *"we exploit the connection between optimal transport and k-means, and rely on entropic regularization to
   derive a fully-differentiable clustering loss that can be
   used in (P) and directly optimized with SGD"*. So you can apply SGD to an MLP, is an MLP the best architecture for using this loss? Depends on your data.

Another approach I could think of using ANNs is [self-organizing maps (or Kohonen maps)](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Eis2470pb/Spring05/FinalProjects/Group1a/tutorial/som.html#:%7E:text=Self%2DOrganizing%20Map,by%20grouping%20similar%20data%20together.). It depends how relaxed is your definition of MLP, you can certainly add a bunch of layers between the input layer and the output feature maps.

You can potentially use a MLP to embed your data in to a vector space, which you can use to compute some metric during KMeans (eg Euclidean distance) which might or might not make sense, depending on how you compute the embeddings and the dataset.

You could do this with an Autoencoder in the absence of labels, though that is a bit more complex than a simple MLP:

[image]

This could be an overkill though, it really depends on the problem. Consider doing KMeans on your data first (no MLP). If the problem is complicated enough, moving the data to latent space could work, this is essentially what word2vec does and people do clustering and all sort of things with it (see [this](https://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/))

Comment: Autoencoder does not help us perform clustering on non-labeled dataset like k-means. I wanna do clustering with a change in MLP.

Comment: What you need to change (or define) is the learning problem, not the architecture per se. I've edited the answer without using K-means, but still requires some changes beyond the MLP (really depends on what you mean by a-change)